# How to turn off MySQL strict mode in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-connection, strict

Upgrading to Rails 4, it seems MySQL strict mode is now on by default for Rails connections. I say this because my Rails app is getting "Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column" when saving a string value longer than 255 characters. Yet, I paste the same query into MySQL console (where global strict mode is reported to be off) and it works fine, just with truncation warnings. As further evidence, [it says here](http://www.mavengineering.com/blog/2012/12/06/turning-on-strict-mode-for-mysql-installed-with-homebrew/) "Rails 4 both use strict mode by default".

My question is how can I turn strict mode off from the Rails app? I'd rather avoid upgrading everything to support it right now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can set strict mode in your database.yml using `strict: false` as follows:

```
production:
  host: ...
  username: ...
  strict: false
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.8/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html

Comment: Great, this is working for me and documented. Looks like the right choice.

Comment: I agree, tested on my code and seems to be the right choice for rails 4, not for rails 3.2

Answer (score 12):

The `mysql2` gem exposes an option to execute an [initial command on connect and reconnect](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#initial-command-on-connect-and-reconnect). You can set the `init_command` from inside `database.yml`:

```
production:
  host: ...
  username: ...
  init_command: "SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = ''"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only one that worked for a rails 3.2 app.

Comment: This solution also works for a Rails 5.2 app, if instead of appending to the current SQL MODE you want to override it entierly

Answer (score 7):

You can add this to your database.yml

```
variables:
   sql_mode: 'traditional'
```

or

```
variables:
   strict_mode: false
```

See:

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8346

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. I tried `innodb_strict_mode` (that's the actual variable), but setting it to "OFF" or false still causes this error when saving a record. What's odd is the variable was recognised because if I try any random variable name in the same place, it throws an exception when Rails start.

Comment: Worked for me. See also https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25924 for a recent change in rails 5.

Answer (score 6):

Following @edubriguenti's answer, [I found this](http://gabrito.com/post/configuring-mysql-sql-mode-in-ruby-on-rails). Applying the post and the comment there, I added the following to `environment.rb` and it looks to have solved the problem.

```
# Set MySQL to clear sql mode for all connections
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter 
  alias :connect_no_sql_mode :connect
  def connect
    connect_no_sql_mode
    execute("SET sql_mode = ''")
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reconnect!
```

Comment: FYI for future people seeing this, this sometimes did not work for me on rails 4.0.3 - in production, the sql_mode is somehow still set to strict sometimes.  I'll try setting it in database.yml as well, perhaps they fixed that setting.

Comment: Okay. It's working for me afaict on 4.1 beta. Please update with results of database.yml as I didn't try it yet and it's obviously cleaner if it works.

Comment: I started having a problem with this where it no longer entered strict mode as expected. Finding @nimblegorilla's answer works properly.

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/34432139/520567 ?

Answer (score 2):

@arya 's answer might not work because `'traditional'` sql mode **is** strict, if you want to set it to non-strict, try this:

```
sql_mode: ''
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Worked for me as of Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
# Set MySQL to clear sql mode for all connections
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter 
  alias :connect_no_sql_mode :connect
  def connect
    connect_no_sql_mode
    execute("SET sql_mode = ''")
  end
end
```

Comment: This was a good starting point, but causes an error with modern Rails. Revised in my answer above.