# How to turn off MySQL strict mode in Rails 3.2.x

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I recently updated from Rails 3.2.9 (Ruby 1.9.2) to Rails 3.2.0 (Ruby 2.0.0).
I have been getting errors from MySQL regarding some data being too long for columns.
I came across this stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420122/how-to-turn-off-mysql-strict-mode-in-rails), but it seems like the solution is for Rails 4.x only: I tried setting `strict: false` in my database.yml, but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
   SET @@global.sql_mode= '';
```

or you can add it in your file

```
   sql_mode: 'traditional'
```

or too

```
   strict_mode: false
```

Comment: Kindly post a sample database.yml file. I am unable to make the suggestions work

Comment: Currently I'm not working with rails. You need to look for database.yml file. Inside there you will find the variables  sql_mode or strict_mode. If not exists you should create.



http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/MysqlAdapter.html

Comment: Setting the global.sql_mode in MySQL directly worked. Seems like the sql_mode in MySQL 5.6.x is STRICT_TRANS_TABLE.